# App crashes on running an infinite loop in a thread on Android.

Tags: android, multithreading, crash

I have an Android service as follows:

```
public class TestService extends Service {

    .
    .
    . // Variables
    .
    private Thread ChangeColors;
    private final int[] colors = {Color.BLACK, Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN};

    @Override
    public void onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startID) {

        LinearLayout layout = TestActivity.getLayout(); // Returns the layout from the activity class
        changeColors = new Thread() {

             int index = 0;


             @Override
             public void run() {

                  while(!isInterrupted()) {

                       try {

                            layout.setBackgroundColor(colors[index]); // Set the background to the Color at the index'th position in the array.
                            index ++; // Increment the index count. This will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException once the index > colors.length
                       } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {

                            index = 0; // Then simply set the value of index back to 0 and continue looping.
                       }
                  } 
             }
        };

        changeColors.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    .
    .
    Other methods
    .
    .

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        changeColors.interrupt();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This service simply gets the `android.widget.LinearLayout` instance from the `Activity` on a button click and keeps changing the `LinearLayout`'s background color.

This is the activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {


    private static LinearLayout layout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
        ));

        Button butt = new Button(this);
        butt.setText("Start thread!");
        button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        ));


        layout.addView(butt);
        setContentView(layout);


        butt.setOnClickListener(

            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    butt.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                    startService(getContextBase(), TestService.class);
                }
            }
        );

        // I have another button coded here which on clicking calls the stopService() method.
    }



    public static LinearLayout getLayout() {

        return layout;
    }
}
```

The program seems to be pretty simple. The app starts up just fine on my `LG-L90` phone. But as soon as I click the button `butt`, the color of the `butt` changes to black, and the app crashes immediately without running the loop in the `Service`.

Where am I going wrong? Please help. I really want to see how threads help in doing such stuff and constantly change the GUI which might help me in game development someday.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have to do UI manipulations in UI Thread. put those part of code in `runOnUiThread` .

Comment: Can you please write the code for me? M new to android. But experienced with Java. Never written a multi-threaded app though.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `runOnUiThread` for UI manipulation.

```
    public class MyService extends Service {

    Handler handler;

    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    private void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
        handler.post(runnable);
    }

    ...
}
```

and make sure that you imported `android.os.Handler` , now call `runOnUiThread` method.

Comment: runOnUiThread() is a method in `android.app.Activity`. Is there any way I can invoke it from `android.app.Service`?

Comment: see my updated answer. you have to use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)